# Replace REGEX in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to modify an HTML file using Powershell, but replacing `[DISPLAY_NAME]` is not possible because of the `[` and `]` symbols.

```
(Get-Content ".\hi4.htm") -replace '[DISPLAY_NAME]', 'tulpa' | Set-Content '.\hi4.htm'
```

But output looks like the following. Please check and help.

```
<httulpatulpa>
<botulpatulpa>
<ttulpabtulpatulpa tulpattulpatulpatulpa="wtulpatulpath: 579tulpax;" bortulpatulpar="5" ctulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpactulpatulpag="0" ctulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpag="0">
<tbotulpatulpa>
<tr>
<ttulpa tulpattulpatulpatulpa="fotulpat-ftulpatulpatulpatulpatulpa: Htulpatulpavtulpattulpactulpa, tulpartulpatulpatulpa, tulpatulpatulpatulpa-tulpatulpartulpaf; fotulpat-tulpatulpaztulpa: 18tulpax; wtulpatulpath: 577tulpax;" htulpatulpaght="64"><tulpatrotulpag>  [tulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpatulpa] </tulpatrotulpag>&tulpabtulpatulpa;<tulpatulpag tulpattulpatulpatulpa="fot
```

Comment: If you're literally replacing `'[DISPLAY_NAME]'`, you can do it with a string replace.  You don't need regex to replcae a literal string.

Comment: escape the brackets with backslash... e.g: `-replace '\[DISPLAY_NAME\]'`

Comment: Instead of using the regex-enabled `-replace` operator, consider using the non-regex-enabled [`.replace()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: This is XML or HTML. Don't parse it with a regex. Use a dedicated parser.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have indicated, there's no need to use the `-replace` operator (which uses the regex engine) for something as simple as this. Just use the normal [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace) method.

```
(Get-Content ".\hi4.htm").Replace('[DISPLAY NAME]','tulpa') | Set-Content '.\hi4.htm'
```

If you insist on using regex, you need to escape the special characters in your string like this.

```
 (Get-Content ".\hi4.htm") -replace '\[DISPLAY_NAME\]', 'tulpa' | Set-Content '.\hi4.htm'
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can replace `[DISPLAY_NAME]`, you just need to escape the `[]` when using the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#replacement-operator) operator. To use your provided code above, note the change below:

```
(Get-Content ".\hi4.htm") -replace '\[DISPLAY_NAME\]', 'tulpa' | Set-Content '.\hi4.htm'
```

You can also use the [`[string].Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) method as well, which does not use regex, just a string to look for to replace:

```
(Get-Content ".\hi4.htm").Replace('[DISPLAY_NAME]', 'tulpa') | Set-Content '.\hi4.htm'
```